# Change td class depending on value?

Tags: php, html, css, if-statement, tablerow

I have rows in a table which I want to change the class of some of the elements depending on the value. What I have now:

```
<td><span class="label label-warning">".$rows["riskScoreText"]."</span></td>
```

- If the value of "riskScoreText" is "High" it should have the label-warning class.
- If the value of "riskScoreText" is "Low" it should have the label-success class.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Without javascript?

Comment: Is this being output by server (PHP, JSP) or client (JavaScript, jQuery) side technology?

Comment: PHP is driving the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$value = $rows["riskScoreText"];

if($value == 'High') {
$class = "label label-warning";
} else {
$class = "label label-low"; }

<td><span class="<?php echo $class>">".$rows["riskScoreText"]."</span></td>
```

Of course, if you have more than two classes, you can add them using elseif statements.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the extra quotation marks I'm assuming you have pulled this out of an existing echo. So it would look something like:

```
echo '<td><span class="label ';
    if($rows["riskScoreText"] == 'High'){ echo "label-warning"; } 
    elseif($rows["riskScoreText"] == 'Low'){ echo "label-success"; } 
echo '">'.$rows["riskScoreText"].'</span></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running a loop

```
<?php
  foreach( $array as $rows ) {
    if( $rows["riskScoreText"] == "High" ) {
        $class = " label-warning";
    } elseif( $rows["riskScoreText"] == "Low" ) {
        $class = " label-success";
    } else {
        $class = ""; //NO STYLE?
    }
?>
    <td><span class="label<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $rows["riskScoreText"]; ?></span></td>
<?php
  }
?>
```